# making awk split faster

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I want to split a long line of data into multiple variables and output into a file. I basically pick and choose only what is required from this long line of data. This is what I have which works fine. But its TOO SLOW for large data files.

```
data in out
------------
out="date:21.05.2015#1time:22.00.05#2host:hostname1#3server:managed22#4msg:text_data#5from=system1#6to=system2#7seq=12dfr#8compName=traffic_sys#9type=bus123#10text=message_head,message_body;junkdata"

awk stmt
--------
echo $out | awk '{split ($0, a, "date:");VAR=a[2];split (VAR, a, "#1");date=a[1];VAR=a[2];split (VAR, a, "time:");VAR=a[2];split (VAR, a, "#2");time=a[1];VAR=a[2];split (VAR, a, "host:");VAR=a[2];split (VAR, a, "#3");host=a[1];VAR=a[2];split (VAR, a, "server:");VAR=a[2];split (VAR, a, "#4");server=a[1];VAR=a[2];split (VAR, a, "msg:");VAR=a[2];split (VAR, a, "#5");msg=a[1];VAR=a[2];split (VAR, a, "from=");VAR=a[2];split (VAR, a, "#6");from=a[1];VAR=a[2];split (VAR, a, "to=");VAR=a[2];split (VAR, a, "#7");to=a[1];VAR=a[2];split (VAR, a, "seq=");VAR=a[2];split (VAR, a, "#8");seq=a[1];VAR=a[2];split (VAR, a,"compName=");VAR=a[2];split (VAR, a, "#9");compname=a[1];VAR=a[2];split (VAR, a,"type=");VAR=a[2];split (VAR, a, "#10");type=a[1];VAR=a[2];split (VAR, a, "text:");VAR=a[2];split (VAR, a, ",");text=a[1];OFS="~dlimit~"; outVAR=date " " time;print seq,outVAR,msg,from,to,type,compname,text,host,server,$0 > "prad.out";}'
```

Can you suggest a way to do this much faster? current speed is 269K records processed in 29mins. Thanks.

Comment: this is a bit broad. Please try to provide a [mcve] so it is more clear. Also, what about using regexp with matches groups?

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input (ie. get rid of all the `...`s) and the expected output given that input. Right now we can help you write the most efficient code because you haven't shown us exactly what it is you want the code to do.

Comment: Example source data would be useful I think. But your limiting factor is _likely_ to be file IO, and not much can help with that.

Comment: hi.. I've done the edit now. This example of $out will run repeatedly for many hundred thousands of records looping the awk statement for each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` with [multiple delimiters](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/07/awk-10-examples-to-read-files-with.html) as shown below:

```
bash-4.1$ out="DATE:23072016#1TIME:060000#2HOST:managed2#3SERVER:host1234"
bash-4.1$ echo $out | awk -F'[:#]' '{date=$2; time=$4; print date, time}'
23072016 060000
```

You can extend the above example to fit your need. I have not tested the performance but i am pretty sure this should be faster than invoking multiple `split`.

**NOTE:** This will work only if the fields are fixed as in date is the first field followed by time and so on.

Comment: Thank you Fazlin. But the problem is, my delimiters vary for different fields. So I am unable to use a generic field separator. Do you think there could be another way to do this?

Comment: From your input string, i guess we can still use my solution without worrying about the number after `#` if we use `:` and `#` as delimiters as denoted in my edited post.